# Via foreground NDEF pushing for API level 10 to 13, can I emulate between two non Android devices?

Tags: android, blackberry, nfc

Via foreground NDEF pushing for API level 10 to 13, can I emulate between two non Android devices?

I have one Android and one Blackberry NFC enabled device. How can I do emulation between these devices in API level 10?

```
package com.app.app.nfctag;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NFCDeveloper extends Activity{
     NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
     private NdefMessage pushMessage;

       // TextView textView;


     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
            if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
                return;
            }

            String text = ("Beam me up, Android!\n\n" + "Beam Time: " + System
                    .currentTimeMillis());
            pushMessage = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { createMimeRecord(
                    "application/com.example.android.beam", text.getBytes())

            });



     }

     /*public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(N event) {
            String text = ("Beam me up, Android!\n\n" +
                    "Beam Time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(
                    new NdefRecord[] { createMimeRecord(
                            "application/com.example.android.beam", text.getBytes())
             *//**
              * The Android Application Record (AAR) is commented out. When a device
              * receives a push with an AAR in it, the application specified in the AAR
              * is guaranteed to run. The AAR overrides the tag dispatch system.
              * You can add it back in to guarantee that this
              * activity starts when receiving a beamed message. For now, this code
              * uses the tag dispatch system.
              *//*
              //,NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.example.android.beam")
            });
            return msg;
        }
     */



        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            // Check to see that the Activity started due to an Android Beam
            if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
                processIntent(getIntent());
            }
            mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundNdefPush(this, pushMessage);
        }

        public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            // onResume gets called after this to handle the intent
            setIntent(intent);
        }

        void processIntent(Intent intent) {
          //  textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(
                    NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            // only one message sent during the beam
            NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
            // record 0 contains the MIME type, record 1 is the AAR, if present
          //  textView.setText(new String(msg.getRecords()[0].getPayload()));
        }
        public NdefRecord createMimeRecord(String mimeType, byte[] payload) {
            byte[] mimeBytes = mimeType.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
            NdefRecord mimeRecord = new NdefRecord(
                    NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, mimeBytes, new byte[0], payload);
            return mimeRecord;
        }

}
```

Comment: update your question: what does it mean "emulate"? What did you do on Blackberry side? Do you use some software on Blackberry to read NFC data or is it you own app? You should write that this is code from Android documentaion! Note that MIME type will not be recognized by Blackberry, since it is custom MIME type and it will not work without extra software even with another Android device!

Comment: Thanks for reply.
i have to share Tag from Nfc android device to Nfc blackberry device.

Comment: i am not using any software at blackberry,simply i have to make app in android to push tag into other Nfc related device ,but i am not able to share tag with blackberry device.

Comment: ya this is a code from android documentation,actully i have to implement Nfc in my android apps ,if you have some code or link please share..thanks

Answer (score 0):

NDEF push works from Android device to Blackberry, just like to another Android device.

UPDATE:

You're right. It only works starting from API 14. Before that, Android uses the NPP protocol exclusively; SNEP (which BB supports) is only implemented from API 14.

Comment: but i m not able to do that ,here my code please review if i have done some mistake

Answer (score 0):

NDEF is most common NFC standard which is utilized by most of other systems.

Comment: but i m not able to do that ,here my code please review if i have done some mistake